# comment about closed-as-duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate

A question of mine got closed as a duplicate of another, with several fast votes.

While there is *some* overlap, in my opinion it wasn't 100% the same, where can I comment specifically about the decision, except on the older question?  It's only a mild disagreement/fair warning.

I had already read through the previous question; none of its answers were completely satisfactory.  However one answer to my question(before it got closed) hit the nail right on its head.  So I'm happy; I just felt others searching in the future should be warned about the more ideal(but closed) solution.

Comment: Referring to http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33768/13496

Comment: Nevermind; I guess when they search they can still see the closed-as-duplicate ones and choose to read if they want.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't merge it because I thought that answer was already on the older question, but it said `retty`, not `reptyr`. It's merged now (and I deleted your "it should be merged" answer). As to your question here, posting on meta or flagging for mod attention are good ways to point out a bad close, although in this case I think it makes sense to call them duplicates; answers to one are going to be answers to the other

Answer (score 2):

I didn't think your question was different from that duplicate. This is a commonly asked question, with many variants that don't significantly influence the nature of the answers; the duplicate I suggested is the one we tend to use as a canonical set of answers.

I admit that canonical set of answers isn't that great; any effort to improve it by discussing the pros and cons of the various tools is welcome.

In general, if you object to a closure, Meta is the right place; you can reply to the comment, as well (which might trigger a response from the first closer who left a comment, and might dissuade other people from closing — it takes five votes or a moderator to close a question).

If you've read a previous question and found the answers unsatisfactory, it's highly recommended that you cite that previous question in your own question, and explain how your question is different.

Comment: Regarding that last suggestion, that I did. I was the one to first bring the alleged dup to the comments of my question, and point why those answers fell short. Even before having found it I remembered having previously used `retty` and hitting the funny textmode problem that `reptyr` handled ok. Meanwhile I also agree that upkeeping a high-quality site of knowledge such as this doesn't always entail 100% unanimous consent. So good job guys. As to a secondary issue I alluded to in another comment(now gone), I could always turn that into its own question if it's important, which it isn't very.